# First call to trans() prepends the string with a dollar sign($) in laravel-blade

Tags: php, internationalization, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a master template with all the html and body elements and then the contents section. My login page is extending the master template. Now when I use the `{{ trans() }}` method in the template, no matter what I do, the first call yields a result prepended by a $. For example `{{ trans('main.loign') }}` yields `$Login`!!!

This does not happen in other templates that extend the master template.

---

## Update:

This problem happens on all template that extend the master template.

---

The code for the template:

In this code if I remove `trans('main.login')` the same happens to the result of 
`trans('main.email_address')`!!!

[image]

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
            <h2 class="text-muted">{{ trans('main.login') }}</h2>
            <form action="#" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">{{ trans('main.email_address') }}</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"
                           placeholder="{{ trans('main.email_address') }}" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">{{ trans('main.password') }}</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"
                           placeholder="{{ trans('main.password') }}" />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me" checked="checked" />
                        {{ trans('main.remember_me') }}
                    </label>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: I very much doubt this is an issue with `trans()`. Have you checked the translations files to see if you accidentally put a `$` there?

Comment: @ceejayoz Of course I have, but as I mentioned If I remove the login translation, the same happens to the next guy! Weird, huh?

Comment: That sounds like someone accidentally typed `$` at the top of one of the translation classes. When Laravel does `require_once` to load the functionality, it gets output, but only once. Check the top of `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Translation/Translator.php` (or blow away your `vendor` directory and do a fresh `composer install`, even).

Comment: composer says `Nothing to install or update`. Should I delete the vendor directory?

Comment: Yes, you'd delete the vendor directory before doing the `composer install`.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I'm not very comfortable around composer, unfortunately. I'll try that now, but I doubt that the problem lies within the vendor dir. Although I'm kinda certain that you're right and I have accidentally added a $ somewhere.

Comment: That didn't solve it! I'm gonna continue searching for an accidental $

Comment: @ceejayoz Could you please check out the update and see if it means anything to you? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem inside the translation file. Although the problem was not in the translation entry :-|

[image]